# Do Video Cards that are two slots wide need to have two slots?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

My MoBo is a: Gigabyte GA-880GA-UD3H

as you can tell from this picture:

[image]

the two PCI-e x16 slots are not next to each other, but every decent graphics card nowadays is two slots wide.

So if I bought an Nvidia GTX 550ti or another graphics card that is two slots wide, does it actually have to be connected to two slots?

If it does, can you suggest any powerful graphics card that doesn't take up two slots?

Comment: That "Turbo3D" on the board looks like a bad shoop.

Comment: What does Shoop mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So if I bought [a] graphics card that is two slots wide, does it actually have to be connected to two slots?

No. It still only has one connector. It's that the cooling hardware requires two slots worth of space.

Comment: I can't believe how little I knew about hardware when I asked this question...

Comment: @MarkKramer: We all start somewhere; the only difference is that I started a decade and a half earlier ;)